# Task run does not fire in web api sometimes

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, task

I have a problem and I'm eager to get help from you.

I have a web api interface using `async`. What I want to do is to create a task inside it but I don't want this task to block it from returning.

With that in mind, I have written my code like below:

```c#
public async Task Test()
{
    //do something
    Task.Run(()=>{
        //do somethin in task
    });
}
```

That is pretty simple, right? However, I found not every time the Task is running, most time it runs, but not every time. I searched a lot in the web but found nothing, I doubt there is something about web api request life cycle? I have no idea.

So, is there anyone can give me some advance? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks a lot, that is great helpful.